# Onclick change form in angular

Tags: angular

I am using angular 9.Onclick i want to change form.Means if i click on advanced then it must show advanced form and if i click on lite it must show lite.I have written "#here" in the code where i want to do this.

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper linear #stepper style="background-color:white;">

    <mat-step label="Pixels" state="settings" [stepControl]="secondFormGroup" [completed]="isCompleted">
      <div class="form2">
        <div class="form-inline" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" style="background-color:#F5F5F5"><br><br>
          <a href="#" (click)=liteForm2() style="float: right; color: black;">Lite</a> **Here**
          </div>
      <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup" class="insert-data secondFormGroup" [hidden]="isShowDiv">
        <div class="color2" style="height: 200px; display: flex;">
          <div class="left" style="padding-left: 5%;">
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline bottomspace">
            <p><strong>Type</strong></p>
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="revenue" value="revenue">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="revenue">Revenue</label>
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="impressions" value="impressions">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="impressions">Impressions</label>
          </div>

          <div class="form-inline bottomspace">
          <label for="value">Value</label>
          <input type="text" id="value" name="value"><br><br>
          </div>
        <div class="form-inline bottomspace">
          <label for="Flight">Flight</label>
          <input type="text" id="Flight" name="Flight"><br><br>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline bottomspace" style="background-color: #D3D3D3;">
          <label for="Frequency_Capping">Frequency Capping</label>
          <input type="text" id="Frequency_Capping" name="Frequency_Capping"><br><br>
      </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right" style="padding-left: 30%;">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline bottomspace">
          <p><strong>Budget and Capping</strong></p>
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="budget" id="lifetime" value="lifetime">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="lifetime">Lifetime</label>
        
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline bottomspace">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="budget" id="daily" value="daily">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="daily">Daily</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="form-inline bottomspace">
        <label for="Pacing">Pacing</label>
        <input type="text" id="Pacing" name="Pacing"><br><br>
      </div>
        </div>
      <div class="form-inline bottomspace">
        <label for="Flight">Flight</label>
        <input type="text" id="Flight" name="Flight"><br><br>
        </div>
    <div class="form-inline bottomspace" style="background-color: #D3D3D3;">
            <label for="inputState">Impressions per</label>
            <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
              <option selected>Choose...</option>
              <option>...</option>
            </select>
      </div>
      </div>
        </div>

      <div class="color2" style="height: 100px; margin-top: 5px;">
        <div class="form-inline bottomspace">
          <p><strong>Ad Type</strong></p>
          <br/><br/>
          <p>Type</p>
          <input type="radio" id="banner" name="adtype" value="banner">
          <label for="adtype">Banner</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="video" name="adtype" value="video">
          <label for="adtype">Video</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="native" name="adtype" value="native">
          <label for="adtype">native</label><br>
        </div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="color2" style="height: 150px; margin-top: 5px;">
          <div class="left">
        <div class="form-inline">
        <label for="Goal">Goal</label>
        <input type="text" id="Goal" name="Goal"><br><br>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline ">
          <label for="inputState">Type</label>
          <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
            <option selected>Choose...</option>
            <option>...</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <div class="form-inline bottomspace">
              <label for="inputState">Conversion Tracking</label>
              <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                <option>...</option>
              </select>
            </div>
        <div class="form-inline  bottomspace">
              <label for="inputState">Priority</label>
              <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                <option>...</option>
              </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top:10px; float:right;">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light">Cancel</button>
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious class="btn btn-secondary">Back</button>
      <button mat-button matStepperNext class="btn btn-warning">Next</button>
    </div>
        </form> 
      </div>

    </mat-step>

  </mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

My .ts file

This is my ts file i am currently hiding my lite form here and want to show my advanced form here.

````
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-stepper',
  templateUrl: './stepper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stepper.component.css']
})
export class StepperComponent implements OnInit {
  firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
  secondFormGroup: FormGroup;
  thirdFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      secondCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.thirdFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      secondCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  isShowDiv = false;
  isCompleted = true;
  liteForm2() {
    this.isShowDiv = !this.isShowDiv; # i am hiding lite form here and want to show advanced form here.

  }
}
```[![See lite link here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5ki9.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmsul.png
````

Comment: @Chellappanவ i want to show different form when i click on advanced link and different when i click on lite link.Wait also uploading image.

Comment: @Chellappanவ see the image link at last line.

Comment: Use ngIf and switch form based on your boolean value